# Synchronizing DVCS repositories across multiple machines

Tags: version-control, dvcs

What's the best way to keep a DVCS repository synchronized across multiple machines?  I'm a solo developer interested in being able to easily move between my work desktop, home desktop and a (Mac) laptop.  At the moment I use Dropbox to keep files in sync, but I'd like to be able to use some source control specific features.  Is there an easy way to do this peer to peer without relying on a centralized repository?  Is there any particular DVCS that's better suited to this kind of workflow?

**Dupe notes**: Inspired by [How can a mobile student effectively use Dropbox with a source control system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096476/how-can-a-mobile-student-effectively-use-dropbox-with-a-source-control-system), but I'm interested in a DVCS, not Subversion.  Similar to [Synchronizing Git repos across machines without push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734405/synchronizing-git-repos-across-machines-without-push), but I'm not necessarily looking for a Git specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious answer: you need to use some central storage, available from all your computers. Push to central storage, then pull when needed.

Comment: +1. You need an always online server that can act as a central repository, or it will probably get messy. Check out free services on the net, or a suitable linux (or other) machine somewhere.

Comment: Basically any stationary machine can acts as server for the specified configuration, if all three connected to the same LAN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) or [github](http://www.github.com) . Use the cheapest paid account with small fee to get private repositories. Even bitbucket provide 1 private repo for the free account if your budget really tight :)